# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'view_count'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Meanwhile using "view count" in my ecommerce project showing this error ('QuerySet' object has no attribute 'view_count')

views.py

```
class ProductDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'product-detail-view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        slug_url = self.kwargs['slug']
        product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug_url)
        product.view_count += 1
        product.save()
        context["products"] = product
        return context
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_img')
    wholesale_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    amazon_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    warranty = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    return_policy = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: filter does return QuerySet and not an object instance you should use .get() if you expect single instance

Comment: Use this : product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug_url)

Comment: This error occurs when using Get ('Product' object is not iterable). So given the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug_url)
```

This return a queryset, not an object so you cannot access object field like this. Either use .first() to get an object or if you want to update all objects in queryset, then use

```
product.update(view_count = F('view_count') + 1)
```

Comment: Now showing this error "name 'F' is not defined"

Comment: Yes,  Use "from django.db.models import F"